# Can I make the statements in a letter filtering function meet two parameters while preserving the names of the statements themselves?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, parameters

I am trying to make this function run on two parameters whilst preserving the for and if statements, yet not getting rid of them.

```js
var inputletter = "e"

startlist = ["jambee", "dangen", "oragna", "sabotta"];

function filter2("parameter1", "paramater") {
 for (var i = 0; i < startlist.length; i++) {
  if(regex.test(startlist[i])) {
    filter2.push(startlist[i])
  }
 }
}
console.log(filter2(startlist, inputletter));
```

I want the output of the code to show the values that have a letter e in them.

Comment: What is desired output ?

Comment: To output values in startlist that have the letter e.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things you missed in your code.

1. `filter2("parameter1", "paramater")` you need to receive arguments in variable something like this  `filter2(parameter1, paramater)`
2. `regex.test(startlist[i])` here you're not actually building the regex anywhere in your code. You need to build regex first.
3. `filter2.push(startlist[i])` this line doesn't make sense.

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
var inputletter = "e"

startlist = ["jambee", "dangen", "oragna", "sabotta"];

function filter2(inputArr, testStr) {
  return inputArr.filter(e=> e.includes(testStr))
}
console.log(filter2(startlist, inputletter));
```

You can change you code to something like this

```js
var inputletter = "e"

startlist = ["jambee", "dangen", "oragna", "sabotta"];

function filter2(inputArr, testStr) {
  let op = []
  for (var i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
   if(inputArr[i].includes(testStr)) {
    op.push(inputArr[i])
  }
 }
 return op;
}
console.log(filter2(startlist, inputletter));
```